# What would be the best/most efficient way to create an index of integers to loop over?

Tags: julia

I have a set of arrays `M[i]`, `Z[i]` and `C[i]`, with values from i:N

I'd like to extract the indicies of these matrices, given a certain requirement, e.g. if M[i] is 0, or if Z[i] is one.

I'd then like to use these indicies in a for loop:

```
for i in indicies
func(Z[i])
end
```

where `indicies` is the vector of indicies previously extracted.
It should be noted that these indices are not expected to be contiguous i.e. they'd be something like:

```
indicies = [4,6,8,11,17,23]
```

What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: Are those conditions should be met in the same time? In other words, should be `i` added to `indices` if M[i] is 0 or Z[i] is one, or the indeces are unique for every array?

Comment: They are unique for each array. `M[i]` will have an index `Mindex` that is different to `Zindex` and `Cindex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an [XY problem-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) but I think you are looking for the `findall` function. Maybe the MWE below helps?

```
M = rand(Bool, 10)
Z = rand(Bool, 10)
indices = findall((M .== 0) .| (Z .== 1)) # indices where M is 0 or Z is 1
func(x) = println((x + 1)^2)              # a random function printing stuff
for i in indices
    func(Z[i])
end
```